XAMPP, Apache crashes when OpenSSL extension is enabled in php.ini
When i enable  extension=openssl  in my php.ini and restart apache, the apache crashes with the following error:
[Fri Jun 21 17:49:05.001805 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 15484:tid 720] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 21 17:49:05.128223 2024] [core:warn] [pid 15484:tid 720] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Jun 21 17:49:05.134247 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 15484:tid 720] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
i changed
ServerName www.example.com:443


to
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName localhost


in the http-ssl.conf file in xampp/apache/logs/extra because apache was giving me an error
but after making the changes the error is now:
Fri Jun 21 16:40:57.957920 2024] [core:warn] [pid 15228:tid 752] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
i also tried installing ssl certificate and stuff written here:
https://jtowell.com.au/setting-up-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-localhost-when-using-xampp-on-windows/
p.s. in case this is revelant, i am trying to add laravel-lets-encrypt to my project. it requires acmephp which i believes requires me to turn on openssl extension
im new to all this and dont know much, just trying to learn stuff
btw Apache runs fine with openssl extension commented out
UPDATE:
and now when i try to recomment the openssl extension in php.ini and change the apache files back to the way they were before i installed the certificate it still wont work. even though i replaced the apache folder with a fresh one with all the default settings

It is unclear what you are actually trying to do. Please take a bit of time to revise your question, there is an "edit" link below it, use it to add details. Do not add details in comments here, all information should be present in the question.

If you want to use ssl encryption with a http server (https protocol) you need a matching ssl certificate. No way around that. This will never work using the hostname "localhost" in your setup, that makes no sense for https. you need a routable host name ("domain") and a ssl certificate issued for exactly that host name. Do you have that or not?

To me the log file excerpts you post read like exactly that: the apache ssl module realizes that you did not provide a valid, usable ssl certificate and shuts down. That does make sense. I do not see a "crash" anywhere.

You can use a "self signed certificate" along with any host name you chose, but only for testing purpose obviously. And that certificate still needs to match the configured host name in the http server. Question is why you'd want to do that, ssl certificates are free these days. And for local development and test purposes you do not have to setup ssl encryption.

@arkascha thank you for getting back to me. i have really never done anything related to ssl so i have no idea what i am doing. i read what you said. my issue is that my apache wont launch at all. the video i was using to learn how to install certificates on local had no such problems and even when i installed the certificate it didnt launch with this in error log "AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?"

What do you think the latter is an error? To me it sounds like a warning saying that the previous shutdown has probably been unclean.

@arkascha ah, that is because its in the error.log of apache which makes me assume its an error. but i have no idea what to do and how to get around it, ive tried to set things back to how they were and still no luck

@arkascha when i start apache in XAMPP it doesnt start, it says apache shutdown unexpectedly and to check the error.log, when i check the error.log i find that warning and i have no idea what to do

As said: if you provide an SSL certificate that is not suitable for the http host you setup inside your http server then the http server won't start. That makes no sense. Because it won't be able to serve requests. You need a valid certificate if you want to use HTTP over SSL (HTTPS).

@arkascha okay, and if i need to change it all back then how do i do that? do i just disable the openssl extension or do i reinstall XAMPP?

You use a valid SSL certificate. Or you simply disable to SSL extension. Question is what you want. I assume you wanted to try out serving your content using the HTTPS protocol. Nothing against that. You need: 1. a SSL certificate that matches the configured http host (so the domain name you use) and 2. you configure the http server to use it.

If this is a local development environment (or a test environment) then you might not actually have a domain name with a corresponding DNS entry pointing to your http server's routable IP address. In that case you can just use any domain name you like (even a made up one) as long as you take care that the browser you use for testing is able to resolve that name. For that you can either create a DNS entry in your local DNS server (if you have one, maybe your DSL router), or in your local systems resolution strategy (typically a "hosts" file). But you cannot use "localhost" as a domain name.

You can even use a self signed certificate, but that always requires to first accept that certificate in your local setup. No way around that. So that only makes sense for testing purpose, if at all.

@arkascha thanks for the suggestions, i think i have an idea what to do now, ill try it and get back to you

Sure, take your time, be curious. Test, explore, try things. This is not rocket science (well, actually rocket science is not that difficult ...), you will certainly understand and conquer one step after another. That is what we all did and all do on a daily base.

@arkascha Thank you for being so helpful! if i figure this out ill definitely let you know
